# The getter 'category' isn't defined for the type 'Property'

Tags: flutter, dart

I'm trying to build a simple real estate property posting UI. I have created the **class** for property forms like this

```
class Property {
  final String name;
  final String description;
  final double pricePerMonth;
  

  Property({
    required this.name,
    required this.description,
    required this.pricePerMonth,
  
  });
}
```

This is in a separate .**dart** file.

I have two categories for filtering.
one is '**category'** and the other is '**subCategory'.**

In the code below,  I tried to reference it, but it gave me some undefined error about the getter.
The IDE has underlined the **'category'** and **'subCategory'** as the cause of the error.

```
List<Property> _getPropertiesToShow() {
    List<Property> properties = [];
    for (final property in _allProperties) {
      if ((_selectedCategory == 'All' || property.category == _selectedCategory) &&
          (_selectedSubCategory == 'All' || property.subCategory == _selectedSubCategory)) {
        properties.add(property);
      }
    }
    return properties;
  }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You does not define `category` , `subCategory` fields  in the `Property` class. Define these fields as below, your code will work then,

```
class Property {
  final String name;
  final String description;
  final double pricePerMonth;
  final String category;
  final String subCategory;
  

  Property({
    required this.name,
    required this.description,
    required this.pricePerMonth,
    final String category;
    final String subCategory;
  
  });
}
```

Comment: Hello @Thusitha Deepal, thank you. that worked pretty well.

Are you an advance flutter dev?

Comment: Yh,I'm working little bit long with flutter you can see my youtube channel and learn more about Machine learning with flutter and flutter 
https://www.youtube.com/playlist?list=PLiGXMHY0AzAIrwsOw9qI1Pf7WKfzmAHQr